# Render after db connection is completed - Nodejs LevelDB

Tags: node.js, express, leveldb

I'm new to Nodejs, Express and Leveldb.

I created db using level and want to pass parameter.

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
var models_array = [];
db.models.createValueStream()
    .on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.name);
        models_array.push(data.name);
        console.log(models_array); // 1st 
    });

console.log(models_array);  //2nd
res.render('home', {
    title: 'Home',
    models:models_array
});
};
```

This is my code but 2nd *console.log(models_array)* is returning null because they are running asynchronously.
Even 1st console.log is returning what I expected.

How can make this work properly?

So that I can pass proper data to template.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself. I can use .once()

```
var models_array = [];
db.models.createValueStream()
    .on('data', function (data) {           
        models_array.push(data.name);           
    }).once('end', function() {                 
        res.render('home', {
            title: 'Home',
            models:models_array
        });
});
```